# Calculating and Creating Columns for Previous Months. Do Loops?

Tags: sql-server, loops

I am very new to MS SQL Server (I have always been using SAS to pull).

I have program which identifies children which where not seen in a particular month - the criterion is in bold below.  When I run the program this is a example of the result:

**Children which were not seen in the month of May:**

```
Person_ID Child_Name  Case_ID   Stage_ID  Unit  Worker_Name
37938354  Chrismary   25367048  28714173  P5G   Edith
37938357  Michael     25367048  28714173  P5G   Edith
29174158  Bryan       22229090  24456882  P5J   Elizabeth
22426348  Juan        24621782  27258653  P5C   Dalbin
37046338  Nathaniel   25154727  28232513  P5A   Vontaisha
38593370  Natalia     25154727  28232513  P5A   Vontaisha
36266293  Luzarely    25020393  27989836  P5C   Dalbin
35745702  Taneesa     24716363  27417204  P5E   Kathleen
28044496  Braulio     24926432  27909182  P5E   Elizabeth
```

What I need to do is add 5 additional month columns based on the month which I run the program for which will indicate if the child was not seen the last 5 month with  the values 'YES', 'NO', and 'N/A'. N/A is when the child was not included in the dataset for the particular month.

**Example of what I need:**

```
Person_ID Child_Name  Case_ID   Stage_ID  Unit  Worker_Name  Seen_April Seen_March 
37938354  Chrismary   25367048  28714173  P5G   Edith          YES         YES    
37938357  Michael     25367048  28714173  P5G   Edith          NO          YES
29174158  Bryan       22229090  24456882  P5J   Elizabeth      NO          NO
22426348  Juan        24621782  27258653  P5C   Dalbin         YES         YES
37046338  Nathaniel   25154727  28232513  P5A   Vontaisha      N/A         N/A
38593370  Natalia     25154727  28232513  P5A   Vontaisha      YES         YES
36266293  Luzarely    25020393  27989836  P5C   Dalbin         YES         YES
35745702  Taneesa     24716363  27417204  P5E   Kathleen       YES         NO
28044496  Braulio     24926432  27909182  P5E   Elizabeth      YES         No
```

...and continues for Feb, Jan, Dec.

In SAS I could figure this out using a Do Loop but don't know hoe to do that using MS SQL Sever.

Also you'll notice I've had to **hard code** code the date Criterion. In SAS I can use a Macro variable to select the dates Example: %let BegDate= '2013-05-01' and %Let EndDate='2013-05-31'. Is there a may to make macro variables in MS SQL server?

**Here is the program:**

```
SELECT 
distinct
a.Person_ID,
a.Child_Name,
b.Case_ID,
b.Stage_ID, 
b.Unit, 
b.Worker_Name
from 
(select
distinct 
Person_ID,
Child_Name
FROM gw_dw.dbo.DimContacts_Child  
where Unit in ('P5C','P4C','P5L','P5D','P5F','P5G','P5E','P5A','P5K','P5J') 
and (**Contact_Date >= '2013-05-01' AND Contact_Date <='2013-05-31**')
group by Person_ID,Child_Name
having sum(case when (Contact_Method='Face To Face') AND
                     (Contact_Result <> 'Attempted') AND
                     (Participant='Yes')
                then 1 else 0 end) = 0 ) as A 
inner join
(Select distinct --Addtional Query Beacuse there multipal units assigned to a child*/
Person_ID,
Case_ID,
Stage_ID, 
Unit, 
Worker_Name
from gw_dw.dbo.DimContacts_Child
where Unit in ('P5C','P4C','P5L','P5D','P5F','P5G','P5E','P5A','P5K','P5J') 
and (**Contact_Date >= '2013-05-01' AND Contact_Date <='2013-05-31'**)
group by Worker_Name,Unit,Person_ID,Case_ID,Stage_ID
having sum(case when (Contact_Method='Face To Face') AND
                     (Contact_Result <> 'Attempted') AND
                     (Participant='Yes')
                then 1 else 0 end) = 0  ) as B 
on  A.Person_ID = B.Person_ID   
order by a.Child_Name;
```

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No, please stop thinking about "loops" and instead think about "sets" - http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1 http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2 http://www.sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3

Comment: Hi Thanks. Ok, I will stop thinking about Loops. I looked at your links. Not sure a totally understand.

Comment: You first want to generate a very simple set of months. Think about a set `{0,1,2,...}` now think about converting that set to months `{DATEADD(MONTH,0,'20130101'), DATEADD(MONTH,1,'20130101'), ...}` - I think the 3rd post will be most useful but I think you need to read them thoroughly. I don't believe 10 minutes counts as "thoroughly."

Comment: Sorry, I only looked at first post you sent.

Comment: What is the ** in your where clause?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in SQL. Here's a simple example with 2 columns:

```
ID DateSeen
1  1/1/13
1  2/1/13
2  3/1/13
3  1/1/13
3  1/1/13
3  4/1/13
```

If I understand your question right, you want to collapse this to 1 row per ID and 'cross-tab' the DateSeen into 12 columns. Try this:

```
Select ID, YEAR(Dateseen) as Seen_Year,
    sum(case when MONTH(Dateseen)=1 then 1 else 0 end) as Seen_Jan,
    sum(case when MONTH(Dateseen)=2 then 1 else 0 end) as Seen_Feb,
    sum(case when MONTH(Dateseen)=3 then 1 else 0 end) as Seen_Mar,
    sum(case when MONTH(Dateseen)=4 then 1 else 0 end) as Seen_Apr
from @tmp
group by id,YEAR(Dateseen)
```

This will give you (sorry for the spacing):

```
ID  Seen_Year   Seen_Jan    Seen_Feb    Seen_Mar    Seen_Apr
1   2013    1   1   0   0
2   2013    0   0   1   0
3   2013    2   0   0   1
```